# I would like to create a csv file that would contain all the members of a particular AD group

Tags: powershell

I need your help.  I would like to create a csv file that would contain all the members of a particular AD group.  In the csv file, there would be columns username, first and last name, and email address.

I tried to ask for help via Google search, but I get all sorts of things, but not what would work for me.Can you help me?  Do you know of a GUI software that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably learn PowerShell instead of relying on a GUI tool that may or may not be paid for.

See: https://shellgeek.com/powershell-export-active-directory-group-members/

Heres an example to get you started:

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Specify the group name
$group = "GroupName"

# Get the group members
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group

# Select the properties you want
$members = $members | Select-Object SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress

# Export the members to a CSV file
$members | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\GroupMembers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You need to have the RSAT tools installed. In this script, replace "GroupName" with the name of your AD group. The script will create a CSV file at C:\Temp\GroupMembers.csv.